# Search Dropdown display group syncing across web applications

Tags: search, search-scope, scopedisplaygroup

Here is an interesting scenario:

I have a single Search Server (SharePoint 2010) that is connected to multiple farms.  I have a web application in each of those separate farms.

In Search Server I have search scopes for each web application:

- All Sites - Dev
- All Sites - Test
- All Sites - QA
- People - Dev
- People - Test
- People - QA

I go to the root site collection in Dev and set the " - Dev" scopes to be displayed in the Search Dropdown Display Group and they update just fine.

The weird thing is that when I go into the "Test" web application and change the Search Dropdown Display Group scopes to the " - Test" ones, Dev is also updated to show the " - Test" scopes!

I have never come across this scenario before.  Has anyone else seen this or have any suggestions as to why I cannot change the different scopes for the different environments?

Thanks

Comment: Mark have you tried to use the ShowDD_DefaultUrl Drop Down mode and created a Scope Display Group and set each section to use the right ScopeDisplayGroupName?

Comment: No, I "could" create a different Scope Display Group on each environment and that will probably be the way I go if I don't get a proper answer...but it just shouldn't be working this way as the "Display Group" should be a site collection thing and not a centralised Search Server thing.

Comment: You should upgrade to 2013, at least then you can choose what level the scopes are on! If I get a thought I will take another look.

Comment: Yikes... it took us long enough to upgrade to 2010! Not sure the client is quite ready to go through that again!! :-)